# Creating a large PDF with react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation, react-pdf

I am trying to create a tool to print installation templates for house numbers. A user inputs into a form the Text, selects the font, the size and then hits "Create" which creates a PDF a plotter can print.

The issue I am currently facing is that the some of sizes these house numbers come in are upwards of 8" tall. Selecting anything higher than 8" seems to crash the web page. I am not sure whether it's because the size of the text or perhaps it's just unable to fit the text on the page so it bugs out. Is there a way to create a PDF that has no particular page size and just has say 3 inches of padding around the content? Perhaps I am just missing something.

```
import Container from "./Container";
import {
  PDFDownloadLink,
  Document,
  Page,
  Text,
  Font,
} from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import broadsheet from "../fonts/broadsheet.ttf";
import jost from "../fonts/Jost-Regularing.ttf";
import texgyreheros from "../fonts/texgyreheros-regular.otf";

const Preview = (props) => {
  const MyDoc = () => {
    Font.register({
      family: "broadsheet",
      src: broadsheet,
    });
    Font.register({
      family: "jost",
      src: jost,
    });
    Font.register({
      family: "texgyreheros",
      src: texgyreheros,
    });
    return (
      <Document file="/myfile.pdf">
        <Page
          wrap="false"
          orientation="landscape"
          style={{
            fontFamily: props.pdfFont,
            fontSize: props.size,
          }}
        >
          <Text>{props.preview}</Text>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="bg-white p-5 mb-5">
        <p className={`${props.font} text-[8rem]`}>{props.preview}</p>
      </Container>
      <PDFDownloadLink
        document={<MyDoc />}
        fileName="somename.pdf"
        className="bg-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
      >
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
          loading ? "Preparing document..." : "Download"
        }
      </PDFDownloadLink>
    </>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```